# Google Sign in with client.js in Vue, authentication never saved to session storage

Tags: vue.js, google-oauth

I have google sign in integrated in my app (SPA app using vuejs).  It works perfectly, EXCEPT when I refresh the page the credentials are lost and I have to resign in.

I've attempted to use [this](https://github.com/phanan/vue-google-signin-button) package but had the same results.

Here's a jsfiddle of the code I followed: https://jsfiddle.net/phanan/a4qyysrh/
And the code for that fiddle:

```
Vue.component('g-signin-button', {
  template: '<div ref="signinBtn" class="btn-sign-in">Sign In</div>',
  mounted () {
    window.gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      const auth2 = window.gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'YOUR-CLIENT-ID-HERE.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin'
      })
      auth2.attachClickHandler(this.$refs.signinBtn, {}, googleUser => {
        this.$emit('done', googleUser)
      }, error => console.log(error))
    })
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    onUserLoggedIn (user) {
      console.log(user)
    }
  }
})
```

and

```
<div id="app">
  <g-signin-button @done="onUserLoggedIn"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can save google credentials and access them after refresh if you use cookies or session storage.
both are not deleted from browser on refresh.

nice vuejs2 plugin for this are [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) - to handle states and [vuex-persistedstate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate) for saving data persistently on browser with local storage, session storage or cookies.